# How to use bootstrap "modal box" instead of "<a> tag and new page"?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I can show details data in a **new page** using **details.php** using anchor tag like bellow :

```
<a class="btn btn-info"  href="details.php?view_id=<?php echo $row['studentID']; ?>" title="click for Details" onclick="details.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Show Details</a>
```

Now I am trying to learn it to show using bootstrap modal box like code bellow:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Details</button>
```

I have put the code of "details.php" in #myModel section and how I can show details data **using dynamic ID - comes from view_id=** for the code I am trying? 
Please help me to understand my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: you need to use jquery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: you can try this http://www.webslesson.info/2016/09/php-ajax-display-dynamic-mysql-data-in-bootstrap-modal.html

Comment: here, {  href="details.php?view_id=  } tells the details.php which id should be picked up and according to that id (view_id) related data is shown. Can anyone tell me how to tell the modal which ID and related data should be picked?